# Oracle to_date function usage

Tags: sql, oracle

When use of to_date function like

```
select to_date(17,'HH24') from dual
```

it return the `2015/3/1 17:00:00` which starts from the first day of the month. I wonder why the `to_date` function behave like this?

> I expect it starts from the current day,
>   so it will show like `'2015/3/31 17:00:00'`.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get 17:00 on today's date you can do this:

```
trunc(sysdate) + 17/24
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this,I just wonder why to_date is behave like.

Comment: In doc, it says it start from the midnight.

Comment: Because that's what Oracle implemented 20+ years ago, and they can't change it now as it would break thousands of working applications.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question: [Oracle Get only time from To_Date() in a Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042230/oracle-get-only-time-from-to-date-in-a-query)
One of the anwsers may explain the behavior:

> The reason this doesn't work is because this not a complete date. Even
>   when you use a to_date('07/12/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'), Oracle stores the
>   date and time, but makes all the components of the time ZERO. So the
>   actual date stored is 07/12/2011 HH:MI:SS

So maybe it stores correctly the year and the month but not the day.